# Column-Count Height Issue between Elements

Tags: css, column-count

I am having an issue with the column-count CSS property.

I am using it along with media queries to make my pagesmore dynamic when going to mobile.

However I am having the issue of a large gap between my forms.
At the moment I am hard coding a height as a 'fix' but this can't be the right method.

Has anyone experienced this type of problem?

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  .masonry {
    column-count: 1;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .masonry {
    column-count: 2;
  }
}

.masonry {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  padding: 0;
  column-gap: 1.5em;
  font-size: .85em;
  /*********Hard Coded Height Needs to be looked at***********/
  /* height:940px; */
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1px 0 1.5em;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ccc;
  border: 0px;
}

.legendTitle {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
}
```

```html
<form class="masonry">
  <fieldset class="item">
    <legend>
      Heading1
    </legend>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="item">
    <legend>
      Heading2
    </legend>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="item">
    <legend>
      Heading3
    </legend>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMakeLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
      it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
      passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMakeLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
      printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
      of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<form class="masonry">
  <fieldset class="item">
    <legend>
      Heading4
    </legend>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="item">
    <legend>
      Heading5
    </legend>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="item">
    <legend>
      Heading6
    </legend>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/0gtvj652/)

Comment: Forgot this :  https://jsfiddle.net/0gtvj652/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use display grid instead of columns and it's dense setting:

Oops, columns on wrong div - here:

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <form class="masonry">
      .....
    </form>
</div>
```

css:

```
    /* add a wrapper div */

    #wrapper {
      display:grid;
      /* no columns mentioned here because we put them in the @media calls at the bottom of the layout css */
      grid-gap: 1.5em;
      grid-auto-flow: dense;
    }
            .masonry {
        margin: 1.5em 0;
        padding: 0;
        /* column-gap: 1.5em; */
        font-size: .85em;
        /*********Hard Coded Height Needs to be looked at***********/
        /* height:940px; */
    }
    .item {
        display: inline-block;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 1em;
        margin: 1px 0 1.5em;
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ccc;
        border: 0px;

    }
    .legendTitle{
      font-size: 25px;
      font-weight:500;
      font-family: 'Pacifico';
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 699px) {
        /* putting the grid columns count in the media call on the #wrapper NOT the .masonry inner div */
        #wrapper {
          /* column-count: 1; */
          grid-template-columns:1fr;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
        /* putting the grid columns count in the media call on the #wrapper NOT the .masonry inner div */
        #wrapper {
            /* column-count: 2; */
            grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
        }
    }
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0gtvj652/2/

fabulous website: https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example1/

Comment: This unfortunately then doesn't split to one column when going to mobile.

Comment: Hi @RossSummerell - i have hopefully un-derped ^

Comment: Well now this charge everything, sorry for being derpy.